# Let $X\sim\text{Geometric}(1/5)$. Compute $P(X^2 \leq 15)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X\sim\text{Geometric}(1/5)$. Compute $P(X^2 \leq 15)$.

I came up with $P(X\leq 3)=.5904$, but I'm not sure of my methodology.

Applying the square root to each side of the equation gives $P(-3.87\leq X\leq 3.87)$. But since probabilities are positive and the geometric distribution is discrete, I changed this to $P(X\leq 3)$.

Then I calculated 
$$P(X=0)+P(X=1)+\dotsb+P(X=3)$$
using the formula 
$$\left(1-\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x\right)\frac{1}{5}$$
and summed the outcomes.

Is this the way to solve this problem?

Comment: It's the correct approach, but the wrong formula.  $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\leq 3) ~=&~ \sum_{x=0}^3 \color{red}{\underline{\color{black}{(\tfrac 45)}}}^x (\tfrac 1 5)\\=&~1-(\tfrac 4 5)^4\end{align}$$

Comment: Graham made a good observation.  I didn't notice because it was not formatted. Anyway, it is not hard to learn. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, consider giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to respondents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that this random variable non-negative possible values, then yes you are correct,
\begin{align*}
P(X\leq 3) &= P(X= 0)+\dotsb+P(X = 3)\\
&= (1-p)^0p+\dotsb+ (1-p)^3p\\
&= 0.5904.
\end{align*}

Notice that 
$$\{X> 3\}\iff\{\text{The first four are failures.}\}$$
This guarantees that we take at least four failures, and we might see more. Hence
$$P(X\leq 3) = 1-P(X>3) = 1-\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^4 = 0.5904.$$

Comment: You assume correctly. Thank you so much.